# LSTMStateTuple vs cell.zero_state() for RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am confused on what is the correct way to use the initial state tensor in Tensorflow for RNNs. There is almost a 50/50 split between turtorials that either use [LSTMStateTuple](https://medium.com/@erikhallstrm/using-the-tensorflow-lstm-api-3-7-5f2b97ca6b73) or [cell.zero_state](http://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-ii.html).

Are the two the same? If so, why are there two ways?

In one example they use `tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple` to set the initial state and in the other they use `cell.zero_state()`.

Why are there two methods? When to prefer the one or the other? Can you only use `LSTMStateTuple` when you set `state_is_tuple`? If so, does `cell.zero_state()` no longer work?

Comment: The two are different things. `state_is_tuple` is used on LSTM cells, because LSTM cells' state is a tuple. `cell.zero_state` is the initializer of the state for all RNN cells.

Comment: See this for an explanation on why LSTM state is a tuple: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Comment: Yes but if you look at the two examples I provided they use two different approaches for setting up the initial state.

Comment: The first one is more explicit. `cell.zero_state` will initialize the correct state class depending on the RNN cell (state_is_tuple is true or false). This line `init_state = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMStateTuple(cell_state, hidden_state)` can be interchanged with `cell.zero_state(batch_size)` where cell is defined before as `cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(state_size, state_is_tuple=True)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The two are different things. `state_is_tuple` is used on LSTM cells because the state of LSTM cells is a tuple. `cell.zero_state` is the initializer of the state for all RNN cells.

You will generally prefer `cell.zero_state` function as it will initialize the required state class depending on whether `state_is_tuple` is true or not.

See [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3476) GitHub issue where you can see the `cell.zero_state` recommended - "use the zero_state function on the cell object".

Another reason why you may want `cell.zero_state` is because it is agnostic of the type of the cell (LSTM, GRU, RNN) and you can do something like this:

```
if type == 'GRU':
   cell = BasicGRUCell
else:
   cell = BasicLSTMCell(state_is_tuple=True)

init_state = cell.zero_state(batch_size)
```

with the initial state being set up OK.

`LSTMStateTuple` will work only on cells that have the state as a tuple.

**When to use LSTMStateTuple?**

You'll want to use `LSTMStateTuple` when you're initializing your state with custom values (passed by the trainer). `cell.zero_state()` will return the state with all the values equal to 0.0.

If you want to keep state between batches than you'll have to get it after each batch and add it to your `feed_dict` the next batch.

See [this](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs) for an explanation on why LSTM state is a tuple.

Comment: Keeping state between batches is not a reason to use LSTMStateTuple? I can do that with cell.zero_state() also...?

Comment: You're right. You can do that with `cell.zero_state()` too, that is why cell.zero_state is recommended in most cases. Still there is the option pass an LSTMStateTuple between batches.